# Nvidia Drivers Not Available Anymore

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ubuntu-drivers, additional-drivers

A few days ago I installed Ubuntu Studio 20.10, called for additional drivers, and selected Nvidia drives version 455 (see below). `nvidia-smi` worked properly.

Now I done an `apt upgrade`, and `nvidia-smi` is not present anymore, and `nvtop` signals a driver/library mismatch. If I call for additional drivers in software sources, see what it shows:

[image]

Note that **I never manually installed any driver**. Previously, before `upgrade` all these options were selectable, and indeed I selected the first entry.

`nvidia-smi` now outputs the following:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Command 'nvidia-smi' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-455         # version 455.28-0ubuntu1, or
sudo apt install nvidia-340               # version 340.108-0ubuntu5
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-390         # version 390.138-0ubuntu2
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-418-server  # version 418.152.00-0ubuntu2
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-435         # version 435.21-0ubuntu8
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-440-server  # version 440.95.01-0ubuntu2
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-450         # version 450.80.02-0ubuntu1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-450-server  # version 450.80.02-0ubuntu3
```

`nvtop` output:

```
$ nvtop
Impossible to initialize nvidia nvml : Driver/library version mismatch
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, though it was for different reasons.  I saw this post and decided to try

sudo apt install nvidia-driver-450

There were many packages that needed to be installed as a result.  After it was all done, I had the options back again.

Hope that helps :)